# Javascript filtering to narrow items by multiple conditions

Tags: javascript

I know there are a lot of similar problems on this platform but none of them could've helped me out yet (Or maybe I was looking for the wrong explaination).

I have an itemArray with objects and an checkboxesArray of checkboxes with their own value and a category name.

I have a leaflet map with markers for all the objects in the itemArray. However, by checking the checkboxes, I want a filter to narrow down the results. I've managed it to it for countries, or for crops but I can't make then dynamic. With that, I mean that if I pick one item in the crops, i can see all crops but I can't pick a country to see what items that crop have situated in that country. The opposite counts as well where I can only see the markers if there is a country checkbox and a crops checkbox selected.

I've tried so many things but none of them worked out..

My filterFunction:

```
checkBoxesArray.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    markerGroup.clearLayers();
    const values = checkBoxesArray
      .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
      .map(checkbox => checkbox.value)
    filteredEntries = entries.filter(feature => {
      return (values.includes(feature.crops)) && (values.includes(feature.country) && values.includes(feature.crops))
    })
    addPopups(filteredEntries)
    if (checkBoxesArray.every(box => !box.checked)) {
      showAmountOfEntries(entries)
      addPopups(entries)
      filteredEntries = entries
    } else {
      showAmountOfEntries(filteredEntries)
    }
    console.log(filteredEntries)
  });
});
```

The code provided demonstrates the situation where you can only see items if there is and a country and a crop selected.. So picking only a country or crop will return in an empty array..

Comment: Is there some way you can tell which checkboxes are countries and which are crops? Then you can put the checked items in different arrays, and compare them with `feature.crops` and `feature.country` separately.

Comment: The checkbox have names that represents their category.
Can you show a quick example how you would compare them please..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your checkboxes a class indicating whether it's a country or crop, e.g. `class="country"` or `class="crop"`. Then you can test those conditions separately in your filter.

```js
checkBoxesArray.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    markerGroup.clearLayers();
    let country_values = [];
    let crop_values = [];
    checkBoxesArray.forEach(checkbox => {
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        if (checkbox.classList.contains("country")) {
          country_values.push(checkbox.value);
        } else if (checkbox.classList.contains("crop")) {
          crop_values.push(checkbox.value);
        }
      }
    });

    filteredEntries = entries.filter(feature => {
      return (crop_values.length == 0 || crop_values.includes(feature.crops)) &&
        (country_values.length == 0 || country_values.includes(feature.country))
    })
    addPopups(filteredEntries)
    if (checkBoxesArray.every(box => !box.checked)) {
      showAmountOfEntries(entries)
      addPopups(entries)
      filteredEntries = entries
    } else {
      showAmountOfEntries(filteredEntries)
    }
    console.log(filteredEntries)
  });
});
```